# Реализация голосового чата с использованием кодека Opus

Tags: c#, unity3d, аудио, libopus

Хочу реализовать голосовой чат, выбрал кодек Opus так как он имеет лучшее соотношение скорости и качества.
Возникла проблема с его использованием. Аудио проигрывается прерываясь и ужасного качества, я так думаю это из-за того что новые пакеты не успевают приходить, либо я неправильно использую opus. Проверял это все на локальном уровне.

Код енкодера

```
public byte[] Encode(float[] inputPcmSamples, out int encodedLength)
    {
        if (disposed)
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("OpusEncoder");

        int frames = InputSamplingRate / 1000 * 20;
        byte[] encoded = new byte[MaxDataBytes * InputChannels];
        int length = API.opus_encode_float(_encoder, inputPcmSamples, frames, encoded, MaxDataBytes * InputChannels);
        encodedLength = length;
        if (length < 0)
            throw new Exception("Encoding failed - " + ((Errors)length).ToString());

        return encoded;
    }
```

Код сендера

```
public void sendVoiceUDP(float[] buffFloats, int channels)
    {
        Encoder = OpusEncoder.Create(48000, channels, Opus.Application.Voip);
        int length;
        byte[] _data = Encoder.Encode(buffFloats, out length);
        byte[] data = new byte[length + 8];
        byte[] __data = BitConverter.GetBytes(MainScript.PlayerScript.id);
        Array.Copy(__data, 0, data, 0, 4);
        __data = BitConverter.GetBytes(channels);
        Array.Copy(__data, 0, data, data.Length - 4, 4);
        Array.Copy(_data, 0, data, 4, length);
        int numberOfSentBytes = udpVoiceClient.Send(data, data.Length);
    }
```

Код "микрофона"

```
if (isRecording)
            {
                int pos = Microphone.GetPosition(null);
                int diff = pos - lastSample;
                if (diff > Delay)
                {
                    countChannels = buffClip.channels;
                    buffFloat = new float[diff * countChannels];
                    buffClip.GetData(buffFloat, lastSample);
                    _buffFloat = new float[Delay];
                    Array.Copy(buffFloat, 0, _buffFloat, 0, Delay * 25);
                    MainScript.network.sendVoiceUDP(_buffFloat, countChannels);
                    lastSample = pos;
                }
            }
```

Код декодера

```
public float[] Decode(byte[] inputOpusData, out int decodedLength)
{
    if (disposed)
        throw new ObjectDisposedException("OpusDecoder");

    float[] decoded = new float[MaxDataBytes * OutputChannels];
    int frameCount = MaxDataBytes * OutputChannels;
    int length = API.opus_decode_float(_decoder, inputOpusData, inputOpusData.Length, decoded, frameCount, 0);

    decodedLength = length;
    if (length < 0)
        throw new Exception("Decoding failed - " + ((Errors)length).ToString());

    return decoded;
}
```

Код "приемника"

```
 while (true)
            {
                Debug.Log("start");
                System.Net.IPEndPoint recv_ip = null;
                byte[] data = udpVoiceClient.Receive(ref recv_ip);
                int id = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);
                int channels = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, data.Length - 4);
                int length;
                byte[] _data = new byte[data.Length - 8];
                Array.Copy(data, 4, _data, 0, data.Length - 8);
                Decoder = OpusDecoder.Create(48000, channels);
                float[] buffFloat = Decoder.Decode(_data, out length);
                Player player = MainScript.GetPlayer(id);
                if (player != null)
                {
                    float[] summ = new float[player.voice.buffFloat.Length + length];
                    player.voice.buffFloat.CopyTo(summ, 0);
                    Array.Copy(buffFloat, 0, summ, player.voice.buffFloat.Length, length);
                    player.voice.buffFloat = summ;
                    player.voice.countChannels = channels;
                }
```

Код проигрывателя

```
if (buffFloat.Length >= Delay && _buffFloat.Length == 0 && isRecording)
            {
                Debug.Log("в процессе");
                float [] tempFloat = new float[buffFloat.Length - Delay];
                _buffFloat = new float[Delay];
                Array.Copy(buffFloat, 0, _buffFloat, 0, Delay);
                Array.Copy(buffFloat, Delay, tempFloat, 0, buffFloat.Length - Delay);
                buffFloat = tempFloat;
            }
            else if (buffFloat.Length >= Delay * 8 && !isRecording)
            {
                Debug.Log("старт");
                isRecording = true;
                float[] tempFloat = new float[buffFloat.Length - Delay];
                _buffFloat = new float[Delay];
                Array.Copy(buffFloat, 0, _buffFloat, 0, Delay);
                Array.Copy(buffFloat, Delay, tempFloat, 0, buffFloat.Length - Delay);
                buffFloat = tempFloat;
                buffClip = AudioClip.Create($"{player.id}_voice", _buffFloat.Length, countChannels, 48000, false);
            }
            else if (buffFloat.Length < Delay && isRecording)
            {
                buffFloat = new float[0];
                isRecording = false;
            }
            if (_buffFloat.Length >= Delay && !audioSource.isPlaying)
            {
                buffClip.SetData(_buffFloat, buffClip.channels);
                audioSource.clip = buffClip;
                audioSource.Play();
                _buffFloat = new float[0];
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

У тебя код "приемника" написан хреново. Декодироватся сигнал должен не в вечном цикле, а по мере прихождения новых данных. Там должен генерироватся некий ивент который будет говорить "есть новые данные!" и по этому ивенту декодируй.

Скорее всего твоя проблема именно в этом куске кода. Если же проблема не будет решена...

1. Проверить соединение между девайсами. Нужно проверять как скорость передачи так и пинг.
2. Проверить ресурсы девайса. Успевают ли они делать всю работу.

Comment: то есть декодирование в отдельный поток вынести? А по поводу использования opus нет нареканий?

Comment: не, то есть тригерить по ивенту какому-то декодирование, а не в цикле. Не в курсах по поводу библиотек. Просто этот вечный цикл явно до добра не доведет. Скорее всего дело именно в нем.

Comment: этот вечный цикл в отдельном потоке и он прерывается как только подключение разорвано, все же я грешу на то что не правильно кодек использую, но все равно спасибо за совет с ивентами

Comment: Не важно что он в отдельном потоке. Не используй вечные циклы в принципе. Или же таймер используй или же по ивентам. И то таймер использовать исключительно если нету возможности воспользоватся ивентами.